# What are “bots” in Xcode and how to use this feature?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have read about the Xcode 9, and there is an interesting term “bots”, which will do the CI/CD work for you, but didn't get any proper guide. Could anyone help me find the configuration guide on it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH1-SW1

Comment: https://medium.com/xcblog/xcode9-xcode-server-comprehensive-ios-continuous-integration-3613a7973b48

Answer (score 1):

From Apple’s [About Continuous Integration in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/) guide:

> **Bots** are at the center of the Xcode Server automated workflow. Bots
>   build and test your projects with the schemes you specify. Because
>   Xcode Server can access the source code repositories of your projects,
>   you can create and schedule bots to run periodically, on every source
>   code commit, or manually. You can also configure bots to send email
>   notification of the success or failure of their integrations. Xcode
>   Server also allows your bots to conduct performance testing and
>   initiate pre- and postintegration triggers.

---

On how to setup and configure bots, please read [Install macOS Server and Configure Xcode Server](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/adopt_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH3-SW1).